# Active Record helper methods - Using a module versus inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord

Let's say I want to define some methods and helpers that will be available across all my `ActiveRecord` models.

A bit of research tells me there are two general options

## Module

Define a module

```
module MyModule
  def foo
    # ...
  end
end
```

Include it in the model when you need it

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule

  before_save :foo
end
```

## Inheritance

Define a base class

```
class BaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Define as abstract so AR doesn't assume there's a table named `base_models`
  self.abstract_class = true

  def foo
    # ...
  end
end
```

Make all models inherit from it

```
class User < BaseModel
  include MyModule

  before_save :foo
end
```

What are the pros/cons to each - is there any particular advantage in doing it one way? Is there one that's more considered the "Rails way" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is always better to use relationship between classes/modules that is called `has` instead off `is`.

Or in other words it is better to use `Module` instead off the `inheritance`. This is because of latter possible changes, what if you later on the road get requirement to have 2 types of classes, you would have to create 2 `BaseClasses`, and let some classes inherit from one, and other from another.

When you are using modules, you just include the module, and thus you define the behaviour of the class that includes it, the so called `has` behaviour.

To get a good grasp of what is good in code, and what is not, learn Patterns, and read [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Comment: Thanks! The `has` versus `is` concept is a good way of defining an object's relationships